# 64 bit Micrsoft.ACE.OLEDB provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, connection-string

I have 64-bit Office installed on my computer and also the 64-bit Microsoft Access database engine.

Even though MADE (Microsoft Access Database Engine) is installed, Visual Studio is throwing an error as shown in the screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Try to download this from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734

2.Go to Visual Studio click add data source, follow the wizard.

This is the same problem I had before and followed steps from here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officesetupdeploylegacy/thread/cc10d906-0fd8-49ef-a1b0-45814bd70c55/

***`You need to install the x86 version if the target machine is 32 bit or the x64 version if the target machine is 64 bit and your application is built with configuration Any CPU.`***

Comment: Interesting, why the MADE didn't work when I installed from Microsoft website. Anyway thanks @coder

Comment: I think you're using MS-office 2010 which has a problem with the drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing this first: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255

If that doesnt work for you, try the following method:

NOTE: this DOES work for office 2010 even though it is for 2007 office :)

1. download and install this: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=23734
2. in VS click add data source, follow the wizard and enjoy! :)